# Why is my android app's behavior different according to devices?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello recently I made a simple Android puzzle game. It has two Activity classes. First Activity is for Menu options, second is for the Main game.

After pressing the Start button from Menu options of the first activity, the 2nd activity appears/starts. My problem is if i minimize the game from 2nd activity by pressing home button, and come back to the game, it starts from the first activity. And then if I press back button, the 2nd activity comes back.

Why does first activity come to the front when I left the app during 2nd activity? I have no idea why my first activity comes to front.

My manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.senzgames.superword.GameCore"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.senzgames.superword.MainActivity"  >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.senzgames.superword.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

Another thing my device is Sony Xperia E3 android 4.2.2 but I also test it on Samsung s3 it works fine on Samsung. It starts the same activity which I left on Samsung. Why is it acting differently on different devices? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have activated the "kill all activities" option in development tools in your Sony Xperia E3 ?

Comment: no. when i come back to the app first activity appear and if i press back button then the second activity appear where i left the app.